# UIScrollView position in reusable cell affecting UIScrollView position in other cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I'm building an iOS app with Swift where a user can scroll through a feed of images up and down (like instagram) and can also scroll left or right on the cell to see more images. Refer to [this album](http://imgur.com/a/DFxPF)(not able to upload images yet) and see F1 for how the UI is laid out.

My problem is when I scroll over to image 1C, the 3rd cell is also scrolling over to 3C. So when I scroll down to the third cell, it's already at 3C. See F2.

Additionally, if I scroll on the 3rd cell to 3B, it also repositions the first cell to 1B. See F3.

I'd like some help in understanding what's going on...

I've created a custom class for the cell with a function to load the images.
(Where I also initialize the imageView frames, scrollView frame and content size, and other properties which I'm not including in the code below.)

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

var imageView1: UIImageView = UIImageView()

var imageView2: UIImageView = UIImageView()

var imageView3: UIImageView = UIImageView()

func loadImages(#image1: String, image2: String, image3: String){

    imageView1.image = UIImage(named: image1)

    imageView2.image = UIImage(named: image2)

    imageView3.image = UIImage(named: image3)

}}
```

and in my View Controller - cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as CustomCell

    var (firstImage, secondImage, thirdImage) = images[indexPath.row]

    cell.loadImages(image1: firstImage, image2: secondImage, image3: thirdImage)

    return cell
}
```

FYI: This appears to only be happening when the view is the root view controller. It works fine when the view has been presented. ???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableView **dequeues** reusable cells. That means that your horizontal scrollview in your cell will have the same content offset as the cell he dequeued. So if you scroll to let's say contentOffset.x = 100.0 in cell 1 and than scroll down in your tableview, it might happen that one of the following cells will have its scrollview subview with the same contentOffset.
Just set `contentOffset.y = 0` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
Or better: Save the cell's selected imageIndex and set an appropriate contentOffset.

Comment: Thanks! In what function would it be best to save that cell's offset? cellForRowAtIndexPath? And would I then set the appropriate contentOffset in the cell's prepareForReuse function?

Answer (score 0):

Reuseable means exactly that: to speed things up the cells gets reused. But as you are changing view properties these are present when the cell is populated with new values. Set the values back on population in cellF orRiwAtIndexPath or – cleaner IMHO – in cellWillDisplay.